# Proper 5vdc relay module hookup

Tags: relay, dc, power-electronics, power-modules

I've been thinking about this for awhile so I might as well post the question here and see if anyone knows the answer to it.

I have this type of relay module:
[image]
So my question about this relay is:

1) Use the ground wire to the (in)NO->COM(out) for the relay to flow through it when 5vdc is applied?

Or

2) Use the 12vdc power wire to the (in)NO->COM(out) for the relay to flow through it when 5vdc is applied?

And just for the heck of it, I can still use this relay for DC in/output even though it only shows AC in/output on the relay itself?

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking .. i think that something is getting lost in the translation from your language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should switch the live wire, not neutral or ground, switching neutral makes more of the circuit live which reduces safety.

The relay is intended to switch AC, it may be suitable for DC but the maker hasn't marked that on the case of the relay. if you can find the datasheet for this relay it will say if it can switch DC reliably.

Do a search on "JQC-3ff" datasheet